# PHP Procedural Prepared Statement for Mysqli Multi Query

Tags: php, csv, mysqli, prepared-statement

I have a PHP code that opens a CSV file using `fgetcsv` then reads through each rows then constructs a "Insert Into" query and attaches it to a variable named `$MyQuery`. This is the most understandable way for me when trying to update my database using information from a CSV file downloaded from the company website. This is working as I expected using the code below:

```
if (mysqli_multi_query($conn, $MyQuery))
{
    do
    {
        /* store first result set */
        if ($result = mysqli_store_result($conn))
        {
                    mysqli_free_result($result);
        }
    } while (mysqli_next_result($conn));
}
```

Recently I learned about Prepared Statements and how they can secure your queries.

PROBLEM: How can I do multiquery with prepared statement in Procedural Mysqli way? I tried researching, a lot says it isn't possible. Some say it is possible but by creating different variables for each queries which is impossible for me as I will be inserting over 10000 records to my database from the CSV file. Is there any other ways to achieve this?

I'm thinking it can be done by looping through each records then doing a prepared-statement version of `Insert Into` but I thought doing 10000 Insert Into SQL commands would be very slow.

Answer (score -1):

I am not 100% sure what you are asking but fallowing might work. First of all I would use pdo for connecting to a database. Fallowing is just a basic outline of what I think you want to do.

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydatabase', 'myusername', 'mypassowrd');
$query = "
    INSERT INTO table (colum1, colum2, colum3)
    VALUES (:info1, :info2, :info3)
";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
do 
{
    $stmt->execute(array(':info1'=>$my_info1, ':info2'=>$my_info2, ':info3'=>$my_info3));
} while( your condition);
```

There is two advantages for prepared statements. First is security and the second allows to do the same query over and over changing the values.  This will make each of queries fast if you prepare them.

here is a ling that can explain more about prepared statements
http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

I am adding a Procedural way of doing it using mysqli.

```
$query = "
INSERT INTO table (colum1, colum2, colum3)
VALUES (?, ?, ?)
";
if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $query)) 
{
    do
    {
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sss", $my_info1, $my_info2, $my_info3);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    } while( your condition)
}
```

I am not sure why you are using  mysqli_store_result(), mysqli_free_result(), or mysqli_next_result(). Since inserting rows produces no results.

Comment: Thank you sir but like what I explained, I need the Procedural way of doing it, not PDO. I'm new to prepared statements and still learning, for me, Procedural is easier to understand although I was already advised that PDO is better to use.

Comment: To make it clearer, I just need a Procedural Prepared Statement sample of a script for inserting multiple rows of data (records) into MySQL Database

Comment: Thank you, I'll try to use this and will get back to you. I had to use `mysqli_store_result` and `mysqli_free_result` before since I was having issues with running multiple (different) queries in 1 PHP page, and the data being inserted weren't being inserted correctly. I scanned the web and learned that you have to free the previous query before sending a new one. That was the solution that was provided to me and it actually worked